# How do I find the letter with the most occurence? c++

Tags: c++

I have to make a program where I need to find the most occurrence of a letter

```
 string sen;
int counter = 0;
char letter = '\0';

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i--){
    cin >> sen;
        if(sen == "quit"){
            i = 101;
        }else{
            for(int x = 0; x<sen.length(); x++){
                if(sen[x] == letter){
                    counter ++;
                }
                cout << letter << "=" << counter;
            }
        }
}
```

I know it isn't the right way to do it but is there any syntax you guys know that I could use to turn **char letter** into the most frequent letter?

Comment: You only have one `counter` and one `letter` you are keeping track of - that cannot work, since you cannot know which letter is the most frequent one until you checked the entire `sen` - so you need to track the frequency of *all*  letters that occur there (by storing them in some container) and then find the one with highest frequency there

Comment: Take a piece of paper and do the job of by hand. This will give you an idea how to write your program. Basically you need to count the occurence of _each_ letter, and in the end you'll have something like 5 As, 6 Bs, 10 Es etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple array map (if working with char strings):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count[256] = { 0 };

    string sen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        cin >> sen;
        if (sen == "quit") {
            i = 101;
        }
        else {
            for (auto c : sen)
                ++count[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        if (count[i])
            cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " : " << count[i] << endl;
    }

   auto cmax = static_cast<int>(
                  distance(begin(count),
                           max_element(begin(count), end(count))));
   cout << "Max Frequent: " << static_cast<char>(cmax) << " : " << count[cmax] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have to deal with vintage ASCII encoding, the code below should do a pretty efficient job. Once you enter the realm of unicode (e.g. utf8), it gets quite complicated.

Just keep track of each character and how often it shows up in an array of size 256 (could as well be an array of size 128, btw...).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, const char* argv []) {
  std::array<uint32_t,256> frequency;
  frequency.fill(0);
  uint8_t most_frequent_char = 0;
  uint32_t max_frequency = 0;

  std::string text;
  std::cin >> text;
  for ( const auto c : text ) {
    uint8_t uc = static_cast<uint8_t>(c);
    frequency[uc]++;
    if (frequency[uc] > max_frequency) {
      most_frequent_char = uc;
      max_frequency = frequency[uc];
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Most frequent character is: "
        << static_cast<char>(most_frequent_char)
        << std::endl << "It occurs in the text "
        << max_frequency << " times." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A map is the usual way to do this in C++.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<char, int> m;
    m['z']++;
    m['y']++;
    m['y']++;
    
    cout << m['y'] << endl;
    
    auto pr = max_element
    (
        begin(m), end(m), [] (const pair<char, int> & p1, const pair<char, int> & p2) {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
        }
    );    
    
    cout << pr->first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```